# What's this fossil?

Tags: palaeontology

I've no experience on the field. The picture below is a gift given to me and I've completely forgotten what was the name of it. I think it was something like "umanite" but I don't know.
It was found on Mt. Vermio in Macedonia in northren Greece.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about biology in terms of SE Biology.

Comment: What sort of questions does palaeontology apply to?

Comment: Unless you are sure that this is a fossil it is not a biology question. Perhaps you can ask in [earthscience.se] first.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a fossil so I don't see why it should be considered "off-topic" given the designation of "palaeontology" on the site. On Earth-Science "rock identification" is off-topic and questions of biological aspect of palaeontology are off-topic, so I doubt anyone will actually help there either.

Comment: it's not alive. It looks like coral fragments. it's blurred. check out a "fossil ID" forum

Comment: Respected @user53456 can you kindly add that why you think it is a fossil? Also if it is contains microfossils probably it is impossible to tell from macroscopic view.

Comment: Respected @AlwaysConfused I said that I'm "pretty sure" because it was given by a geologist friend back in the university as one. I doubt it was a joke as we were good friends back then. I don't know if it is microfossils as I don't have any experience on the field.

Comment: @user53456 I am not confirming your friend did a prank. Microfossils means any microscopic fossils, which include diatom and other protists' shells, pollens, phytoliths (silica crystal found in plants) etc.  and the summed up group's members are not rare either.

Comment: @user53456 Rock identification is a valid topic in geology. Anyway, since I am not a member of that community, I can't comment much. Palaeontology is on topic here, in my opinion. Can you post another close-up hi res image of the sample so that the identification is easier? BTW, ammonite sounds like your "umanite" but your sample doesn't look like the former (it looks like a spiral).

Comment: Earth scence does allow rock ID questions -- I've asked them! This site does nto handle rock ID, but paleontology would be a valid topic for this site since it *is* related to biological organisms. However, your post does not have a good picture and I doubt very much anyone in this community will be able to give you an answer. I suggest uploading better photos or asking a paleontologist elsewhere to get a better response.